# NSDate returning GMT time

Tags: cocoa, timezone, nsdate

I live in India which is  +5.30 hours GMT. When I print the system time, it shows me the current time. But when I use this code, the GMT time is used!

Code example:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *tomorrow = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:24 * 60 * 60];
NSDate *dayaftertomorrow = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:48 * 60 * 60];

NSLog(@"Tomorrow, the date will be %@" , tomorrow);
NSLog(@"Day after tomorrow, the date will be %@" , dayaftertomorrow);
```

The system time now is 11:34 P.M. but the console prints out :

2013-06-05 23:35:02.577 prog1[1601:303] Tomorrow, the date will be 2013-06-06 **18:05:02 +0000**
2013-06-05 23:35:02.578 prog1[1601:303] Day after tomorrow, the date will be 2013-06-07 **18:05:02 +0000**

Answer (score 4):

After you create you NSDate object, you have to use the NSDateFormatter method stringFromDate: to generate a date string localized to a particular timezone. If you just do a straight NSLog() on the NSDate object it will show the date as GMT by default

Comment: Just to clarify: An NSDate object alone represents *a moment in linear time, independent of any time zone*. When you print it or otherwise display it somewhere, it will print out what day and time in some time zone represents that moment (e.g., “in GMT, that moment was 18:05 on June 6th”). If you want it printed or displayed in a specific time zone, including the user's, use a date formatter that you've set to use that time zone.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

NSLog(@"Now: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Other timezones can be found with `NSTimeZone` like this:

```
NSLog(@"Timezones: %@", [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]);
```

Hope that helps!